# Mailto links on my wiki pages don't work

Tags: email, hyperlink, wiki-pages, chrome, links

I have started adding "mailto:" hyperlinks on some of the wiki pages in my SharePoint site. The link is set up correctly but when I click on it Chrome either does nothing or opens a new Chrome tab.

Is this an issue with Chrome or is there some issue with the links (they are just standard links with "mailto:example@email.com")?

Comment: do the links work outside of chrome? Have you tried Edge or IE

Comment: Links don't work in those either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just experienced this issue as well. What I found was that somehow the default mail application (for opening mailto links) on my computer had changed. Try going to Settings > System > Default Apps and under Email, make sure the correct application is chosen. For me, the default had somehow been changed to Chrome, which is why the links weren't working.

Note that this is for Windows.